# Мини БД на C#

Tags: c#

Я создал регистрационную форму на C#. Это сайт и в нем кнопки: Войти и Регистрация. Надо зарегистрировать пользователя программы у себя на компе. Нужно, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку регистрация, все данные, которые пользователь ввел в textbox'ы, записались в какой-то текст файл. А потом в другой форме, если я наберу эти данные и нажму вход, чтобы он проверил эти данные с текстофайлом и если все совпадает выявить Success. Можно сделать такое? Помогите советами и подсказками, как мне сделать такое, типа маленькой домашней БД.

Comment: Обязательно на C#? Есть рабочая прога на С++ & Qt, работает с файлами с возможностью выбора, поиск, добавление записей - пара изменений интерфейса и кода - вот он результат. Нужно?

Comment: @embarcadero мне просто самому хочется лепить. Нет не обязательно C#, можно и на С++, подскажете как?

Comment: Я могу дать исходник, если конечно нужно. Для его редактирования и компилирования понадобится Qt Creator и Qt 4.8.1, ну или другая версия, можно даже QtSdk. Потяните?

Comment: нет. Не думаю. Может советом поможете?

Comment: вы предлагаете ему сделать сайт на крестах? ну вы и жестокий я вам скажу!

Comment: Я подумал, что он хочет просто бд приложение, про сайт на Asp ни слова, разве нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну при регистрации я бы сделал такой код

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Create("data.txt")))
{
 sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
 sw.WriteLine(textBox2.Text);
 sw.Close();
}
```

А при входе такой код.

```
string username, password = string.Empty;

using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open("data.txt", FileMode.Open)))
{
 username = sr.ReadLine();
 password = sr.ReadLine();
 sr.Close();

 if(username == textUserName.Text && password == textPassword.Text)
 {
   MessageBox("УСПЕШНО ВОШЛИ");
 }
else
 {
  MessageBox("Что-то тут не так");
 }
}
```

Comment: а я бы сделал так:

    ...
    sw.WriteLine(ComputeHash(textBox2.Text));
    ...
    
    ...
    if(username == textUserName.Text && password == ComputeHash(textPassword.Text))
    ...

    public string ComputeHash(string str)
    {
 var hashString = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed();
 return hashString.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str)).Aggregate(string.Empty, (acc, el)=>acc+String.Format("{0:x2}", el));
    }

Comment: Спасибо! Как раз таки то, что нужно!

Comment: @spectre @angus123 посоветуйте мне книгу или сайт, откуда я смогу научиться хорошо С#, для новичка. Спасибо заранее

Comment: @navil1893, напиши мне свою почту, я тебе свою библиотеку скину))

Comment: @Angus123 Спасибо огромное!) o.alizade93@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

[C# и XML. Удобный способ хранения данных. Часть первая](http://dblog.ucoz.ru/blog/2009-03-20-10), [Часть вторая](http://dblog.ucoz.ru/blog/2009-03-20-11)

Для ASP думаю сами модифицируете, но вообще если данных много будет, то лучше использовать какую либо СУБД.

Comment: спасибо! Прочту, если возникнут вопросы, то задам )